# Effect of adhesive on ballistic fabrics

Tags: collision, material-science, projectile, adhesion

Adhesive is applied to "soft" ballistic fabrics (like kevlar or even [fiberglass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7jiIQOgwtI)) in order to decrease [bulge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOfMgXlY3zA) when being hit by a projectile.
What would be the effect of gluing layers of ballistic fabrics together (effectively, making it stiff), with a powerful adhesive, on the fabric's ability to resist penetration?
Obviously, the adhesive itself will also resist the penetration, but that is not what I ask.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for Engineering SE. By the way, if you're going to saw through fiberglass, please, wear a respirator! Fiberglass particles and lungs should never mix. That video hurt to watch.

Comment: @gs Thank you, I will take it there, and about the safety advice, you are absolutely right. Many commenters on YT pointed it out as well.